# Evaluation of Multidimensional Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I would like to have a closed form expression for the multidimensional integral
\begin{equation}
\int \mathbf x^\text{T} \mathbf K \mathbf x \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^\text{T}  \mathbf K \mathbf x\right ] d\mathbf x.
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^d$, $\mathbf K \in \mathbb S^{d\times d}$ is a positive definite matrix, and the integration is over all of $\mathbb R^d$.

I believe such an expression exists, but I don't know how to derive it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=Wy$, where $W$ is unitary and $W^{*}KW=D=diag(\lambda_{1},\cdots,\lambda_{d})$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\left\langle x,Kx\right\rangle e^{-\left\langle x,Kx\right\rangle }dx & = & \int\left\langle y,W^{*}KWy\right\rangle e^{-\left\langle y,W^{*}KWy\right\rangle }dy\\
 & = & \int\left\langle y,Dy\right\rangle e^{-\left\langle y,Dy\right\rangle }dy
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for your help, James.  Do you not need a factor of $|W|$ to account for the change of variables?

Comment: Right, there should be |W|. But W is unitary, so the determinant is 1.

Comment: Ah, of course.  :)  Do you agree with my answer below?

Comment: Yes, that's what I found too.

Answer (score 1):

Following James's hint, I arrived at the following conclusion:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \mathbf x^\text{T} \mathbf K \mathbf x \exp[-\mathbf x^\text{T} \mathbf K \mathbf x] d\mathbf x = \frac{d \pi^{d/2}}{2\sqrt{|K|}} .
\end{equation}