# Evaluation of power times gaussian multivariable integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gaussian-integral

In the context of evaluating the propagation of a flattened Gaussian beam, the following integral appears:

\begin{equation}
\int (\mathbf x^T \mathbf F \mathbf x)^n \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T  \mathbf G \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right] d\mathbf x
\end{equation}
where x and h are 2 by 1 matrices and the uppercase matrices are 2 by 2

A solution to this integral is implicitly used in this paper:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402604701394

that is used to find the propagation integral for a flattened Gaussian beam, however the written solution seems to be wrong.

The only thing reported is that the following integral was used:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^{2n} \exp(-a^2x^2)\cos(xy)dx = (-1)^n \pi^{1/2} 2^{-(2n+1)} a^{-(2n+1)} \exp \bigg (-\frac{y^2}{4a^2} \bigg ) H_{2n} \bigg (\frac{y}{2a} \bigg )
\end{equation}

The closest integral in the exchange I've been able to find is: [Evaluation of Multidimensional Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680107/evaluation-of-multidimensional-integral)

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Include the relevant written solution that appears in the paper within the question. The linked paper is paywalled.

Comment: I'll add it, however the original integral and solution are a lot more complicated because each of the above matrices are composed of other matrices

Comment: You should mention that $\mathbf{G}$, and perhaps $\mathbf{F}$, must be a positive-definite matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that if you have the expression for $J(\mathbf{G},\mathbf{h})=\int  \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T  \mathbf G \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right] d\mathbf x$, then you can calculate any "Gaussian times polynomial" by judicially differentiating (possibly several times) by $h_i$.

Alternatively, consider the expression $$J(\mathbf{G}+\lambda \mathbf{F},\mathbf h)=\int  \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T   (\mathbf G + \lambda \mathbf F) \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right] d\mathbf x$$ and differentiate it by $\lambda$ ($n$ times) and then take $\lambda \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Thank you, I know that procedure but I would need to do the differentiation for every n I want and would like to use this for high n, the solution given in the paper uses a solution using a Hermite polynomial. There is a question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424363/applying-1d-integral-to-matrix-integral which if I understand I might be able to use for this integral

Comment: Would an asymptotic large $n$ result suffice?

Comment: Hi, well the paper seems to have arrived at an explicit solution for any n using the 1d integral above. There is no proof given in the paper and the solution as written seems to be wrong but I think they used a proof similar to the one I posted here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424363/applying-1d-integral-to-matrix-integral but using $()^n$ instead of a hermite polynomial in the first line